# Evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \pi\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sin(\frac{i\pi}{n})}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \pi\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}  \sin(\frac{i\pi}{n})}{n}$

Any helpful hint leading to answer is greatly appriciable.!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Method $1$:**
Note that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\pi}n \sum_{k=1}^n \sin\left(\dfrac{k \pi}n\right) = \int_0^{\pi} \sin(x)dx = 2$$

---

**Method $2$:**
Another way is to directly make use of the following identity

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(kt) = \dfrac{\sin(nt/2)\sin((n+1)t/2)}{\sin(t/2)}$$
which can be proved by induction or by looking at the imaginary part of the sum of geometric progression $\sum_{k=1}^n \exp\left(ikt\right)$.

This gives us that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \sin\left(\dfrac{k\pi}n\right) = \dfrac{\sin(\pi/2)\sin(\pi/2+\pi/(2n))}{\sin(\pi/(2n))} = \dfrac1{\tan(\pi/(2n))}$$
We hence have the limit to be
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\pi/n}{\tan(\pi/(2n))} = 2$$